# ¿Cómo mostrar imágenes de un proyecto en react en GitHub Pages y en Netlify?

Tags: reactjs, github, webpack, sass, img

Tengo un problema con un proyecto básico en react y webpack, el proyecto me funciona cuando lo abro en mi local Host (las imágenes se muestran) pero cuando lo subo en GitHub pages o en Netlify no se me cargan las imágenes, ¿alguien me puede ayudar?

Este es el repositorio: https://github.com/DiegoRojas93/GradiWeb

Este es el deploy en GitHub Pages: https://diegorojas93.github.io/GradiWeb/

Este es el deploy en Netlify: https://brave-curie-afca05.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las imágenes no las tienes en tu rama de [gh-pages](https://github.com/DiegoRojas93/GradiWeb/tree/gh-pages), sino en [main](https://github.com/DiegoRojas93/GradiWeb), deberías copiarlas a la primera.

Comment: Agracias por tu observacion Alter Lagos